# Count the Characters in a String Recursively & treat "eu" as a Single Character

Tags: java, string, algorithm, recursion

I am new to Java, and I'm trying to figure out how to count Characters  in the given string and threat a combination of *two characters* `"eu"` as a **single character**, and still count all other characters as one character.

And I want to do that using recursion.

Consider the following example.

*Input:*

```
"geugeu"
```

*Desired output:*

```
4   // g + eu + g + eu = 4
```

*Current output:*

```
2
```

I've been trying a lot and still can't seem to figure out how to implement it correctly.

*My code:*

```
public static int recursionCount(String str) {
    if (str.length() == 1) {
        return 0;   
    }
    else {
        String ch = str.substring(0, 2);
        if (ch.equals("eu") {
            return 1 + recursionCount(str.substring(1));
        }
        else {
            return recursionCount(str.substring(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the count 4 when `geugeu` has only two `eu`s. The code is working as expected.

Comment: the extra eu was a mistake, my bad. But I need the code to count all characters, but the 4 special cases listed above need to count as one word. So "geugeu" needs to count as 4 characters in the string.

Comment: Then you have to return "2 + recursion...", as the string is two digits long.

Comment: in that case use 2 + recursionCount(str.substring(1)); in your if block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP wants to count all characters in a string but adjacent characters "ae", "oe", "ue", and "eu" should be considered a single character and counted only once.

Below code does that:

```
public static int recursionCount(String str) {
    int n;
    n = str.length();
    if(n <= 1) {
        return n; // return 1 if one character left or 0 if empty string.
    }
    else {
        String ch = str.substring(0, 2);
        if(ch.equals("ae") || ch.equals("oe") || ch.equals("ue") || ch.equals("eu")) {
            // consider as one character and skip next character
            return 1 + recursionCount(str.substring(2));
        }
        else {
            // don't skip next character
            return 1 + recursionCount(str.substring(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Recursion explained

In order to address a particular task using **Recursion**, you need a firm understanding of how recursion works.

And the first thing you need to keep in mind is that **every** *recursive solution* should (either explicitly or implicitly) contain two parts: *Base case* and *Recursive case*.

Let's have a look at them closely:

- **Base case** - a part that represents a simple edge-case (*or a set of edge-cases*), i.e. a situation in which recursion should terminate. The outcome for these edge-cases is known in advance. For this task, ***base case*** is when the given *string is empty*, and since there's nothing to count the *return value* should be `0`. That is sufficient for the algorithm to work, outcomes for other inputs should be derived from the *recursive case*.
- **Recursive case** - is the part of the method where recursive calls are made and where the main logic resides. Every recursive call eventually hits the *base case* and stars building its return value.

In the recursive case, we need to check whether the given string starts from a particular string like `"eu"`. And for that we don't need to generate a substring (keep in mind that object creation is costful). instead we can use method [`String.startsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) which checks if the bytes of the provided prefix string match the bytes at the beginning of this string which is chipper (*reminder: starting from Java 9* `String` *is backed by an array of bytes, and each character is represented either with one or two bytes depending on the character encoding*) and we also don't bother about the length of the string because if the string is shorter than the prefix `startsWith()` will return `false`.

## Implementation

That said, here's how an implementation might look:

```
public static int recursionCount(String str) {
    if(str.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }

    return str.startsWith("eu") ?
        1 + recursionCount(str.substring(2)) : 1 + recursionCount(str.substring(1));
}
```

**Note:** that besides from being able to implement a solution, you also need to evaluate it's *Time* and *Space complexity*.

In this case because we are creating a new string with every call time complexity is quadratic **O(n^2)** (*reminder: creation of the new string requires allocating the memory to coping bytes of the original string*). And worse case space complexity also would be **O(n^2)**.

There's a way of solving this problem *recursively* in a linear time **O(n)** without generating a new string at every call. For that we need to introduce the second argument - *current index*, and each *recursive call* should advance this index either by `1` or by `2` (*I'm not going to implement this solution and living it for OP/reader as an exercise*).

## In addition

In addition, here's a concise and simple **non-recursive** solution using [`String.replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
public static int count(String str) {
    
    return str.replace("eu", "_").length();
}
```

If you would need handle multiple combination of character (which were listed in the first version of the question) you can make use of the regular expressions with [`String.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)):

```
public static int count(String str) {
    
    return str.replaceAll("ue|au|oe|eu", "_").length();
}
```